# rails double .each error

Tags: ruby

```
@sections.each do |section|       
  section.points.each do |point| 
    if point.distance_corrected.blank?
      @total_distance = total_distance + point.distance
    end
  end
end
```

and then I try outputting `<%= @total_distance %>` in my view, I get a

```
NameError in PointsController#calculate
undefined local variable or method `total_distance' for #<PointsController:0x000001030698f8>
```

error.

I'm not sure what's wrong here, but I kind of think it's something about that double loop of mine. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: post the rest of the method, it looks like there is no "total_distance" var defined locally or method in the Controller.

Comment: Do you initialize the @total_distance outside the shown code? Are you sure that the condition is true and the variable is assigned? Do you mean to refer to the instance variable on the right hand of the assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
@total_distance = total_distance + point.distance
```

should probably be

```
@total_distance = @total_distance + point.distance
```

(unless you have a method or local variable "total_distance" defined somewhere in your controller).